# Linq To SQL Method with .Contains fails

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the below Linq To SQL Method.  When I step through the code `spcCodeIDs` contains the seven entries I am expecting.  However I get a run-time exception of

`Method 'Boolean Contains(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

What am I missing?

```
public static DataTable GetSPCCodeList()
{         

    using (var context = ProviderDataContext.Create())
    {
        IQueryable<tblProviderAdminSPCCode> tSPCCode = context.GetTable<tblProviderAdminSPCCode>();
        IList<string> spcCodeIDs = BLLCmo.FCApprovedSPCsForGreenSheet();
        return (tSPCCode
                .Where(spcCode => spcCode.Inactive == null && spcCodeIDs.Contains(spcCode.SPCCodeID)) 
                .OrderBy(spcCode => spcCode.SPCCodeID)
                .Select(spcCode => new { spcCode.SPCCodeID, spcCode.SPCDescription, spcCode.SPCCategoryID }))
                .CopyLinqToDataTable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ to SQL can only support Contains translations form a concrete list and not the IList interface.. try changing your line from

```
IList<string> spcCodeIDs = BLLCmo.FCApprovedSPCsForGreenSheet();
```

to

```
List<string> spcCodeIDs = BLLCmo.FCApprovedSPCsForGreenSheet().ToList();
```

Comment: @Refracted Paladin You Bet! It doesn't really make much sense at first but you get used to the limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string as a parameter to Contains.  So trying passing spcCode.SPCCodeID.ToString()